# Is this image from an anime or manga?

Tags: dogs

[image]

Is this image from an anime or manga? Which one is it from? I found it from a banner of an anime website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That looks like "[Naoto Fuyumine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dogs:_Bullets_%26_Carnage_characters#Naoto_Fuyumine)" from [Dogs](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=4338), which has a manga and anime.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, the original image verifies this (some content may be NSFW): http://www.zerochan.net/1382405#full

Comment: @Eric If you're going to link to the original image, surely [the copy on the artist's Pixiv page](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=32422625) is a more reliable source. Anyway this confirms that the image is by the original manga author and was released at C83 in an artbook.

Comment: @LoganM My bad, Pixiv takes forever to load for me, so I avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought that was definitely just some fan-art.